# How to go from a List of Objects at c#(Razor Syntax) to an array or an object at javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc

The serialization using Newtonsoft.Json creates a json text succesfully:

```
@model IEnumerable<CardGameApp.RootObject>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Game";
    Layout = "~/views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    List<CardGameApp.RootObject> deck1 = Model.Take(40).ToList();
    List<CardGameApp.RootObject> deck2 = Model.Skip(40).ToList();

    var json1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deck1); 
    var json2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deck2);
}
```

Whereas the 2nd task throws an error like:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse ()
```

```
var _deck1 = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(json1));
var _deck2 = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(json2));
```

And if i put '' inside the parenthesis like this:

```
var _deck1 = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(json1)');
var _deck2 = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(json2)');
```

It throws an error like:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.
```

Any tip will be helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

Since JSON is valid JavaScript code, all you have to do in the JavaScript is:

```
var _deck1 = @Html.Raw(json1);
var _deck2 = @Html.Raw(json2);
```

Basically, the JSON becomes a JavaScript object literal in your script tag.